# Refactor method chaining javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I call a function with bunch of nested method, i'm using web scraping tools called cheerio and i want to get the text out of it so i need to call a bunch of function. here's my example code.

```
        var text = $(el)
          .children()
          .first()
          .children()
          .first()
          .children()
          .first()
          .text()
          .replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");
```

My question is, how can i simplify my function so I have the same result without chaining my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive solution could be

```
var text = $(">*:nth-child(1)".repeat(3), el).text().replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

For a good solution we'd need more context. Like what does the markup look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth-child(1)` selector for the select first child.

You can use like that

```
$("div div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) ul:nth-child(1)").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop

```
let child = $(el).children().first()
if (child) {
 while (child.children().first()) {
   child = child.children().first()
 }
 child.text().replace(/\s\s+/g, " ");
}
```